# Bloqueo de tabla causado por trigger MysQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mybatis

Actualmente tengo un problema al parecer con unos triggers en una de mis tablas ya que se bloquea, al hacer pocos "INSERTS" a la tabla funciona correctamente pero al hacer muchos INSERTS simultaneos (estoy usando **JMeter** para pruebas de carga) aparece un `DeadLock` en la tabla..

En la tabla hay 2 tipos de Trigger `AFTER INSERT` y `BEFORE INSERT` en el `AFTER INSERT` hay muchas cosas que se hacen y lo elimine temporalmente, solo deje el `BEFORE INSERT` y de igual manera existen bloqueo en la tabla.

Aqui el codigo del trigger:

```
DELIMITER 
CREATE
TRIGGER `getNextIdTicket` BEFORE INSERT ON `pos_doc_ticket` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF (new.id_cat_producto = 0 AND new.buscaNuevoRegistro=TRUE)
THEN 
    SET new.id_doc_ticket = getNextSeq (
    new.id_cat_zona,
    new.id_cat_empresa,
    new.id_cat_tienda,
    "idTicket"
 );

END IF;
IF new.id_cat_producto>0
THEN
  SET new.id_linea = getNextSeqLine (
    new.id_cat_zona,
    new.id_cat_empresa,
    new.id_cat_tienda,
    new.id_cat_caja,
    new.id_doc_ticket
  );

   END IF ;
  END;
 DELIMITER ;
```

Y la funciojn que llame es esta:

```
DELIMITER
CREATE  FUNCTION `getNextSeq`(idZona BIGINT, idEmpresa BIGINT, idTienda  
BIGINT, sSeqName VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS BIGINT(10) UNSIGNED
BEGIN
DECLARE nLast_val BIGINT;
IF idTienda > 0 THEN 
SET nLast_val =  (SELECT seq_val 
                  FROM _sequence 
                  WHERE seq_name = sSeqName);
ELSE
SET nLast_val =  (SELECT seq_val 
                  FROM _sequence 
                  WHERE seq_name = sSeqName);
END IF;
IF (nLast_val IS NULL OR nLast_val = 0)THEN
    SET nLast_val = 1;
    INSERT INTO _sequence (id_cat_zona,id_cat_empresa,id_cat_tienda,seq_name,seq_val) 
    VALUES (idZona,idEmpresa,idTienda,sSeqName,nLast_Val);
ELSE
    SET nLast_val = nLast_val + 1;
    UPDATE _sequence SET seq_val = nLast_val 
    WHERE seq_name = sSeqName;
END IF;
RETURN nLast_val;
END
DELIMITER ;
```

Como pueden ver lo uso para obtener un id consecutivo para insertarlo en la tabla antes del INSERT pero cuando hago al rededor de 100 peticiones simultaneas al llegar al momento de los INSERTS existen varios bloqueos de la tabla por la cual no todas los INSERTS terminan con éxito.

Espero puedan ayudarme y ver que solucion puede existir.

Comment: Creo que en MySql puedes crear SEQUENCES sin necesidad de hacerlo tu mismo

Comment: es correcto en mysql no existen las secuencias así que trate de simular una pero al parecer hay problemas cuando son transacciones simultaneas... y no se de que otra manera podría hacerlo.

Comment: De hecho yo tengo una tabla así con el nombre y el valor que corresponde la tabla se llama "_sequence " que es donde la función actualiza al obtener el siguiente id y actualizarlo.

Answer (score 0):

En **MySQL** no existen secuencias como tal.

El problema es que tu trigger cuenta las cantidad de registros que hay, cambiar un poco tu codigo en lo siguiente:

la tabla la haria de esta forma:

```
CREATE TABLE `_sequence` (
      `seq_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `seq_val` bigint(20) NOT NULL
      ADD UNIQUE KEY `_sequence` (`seq_name`);
```

ahora cambiaria tu funcion de sequencia:

```
DELIMITER 
CREATE  FUNCTION getNextSeq(_seq_name VARCHAR(50)) 
RETURNS BIGINT(20)
BEGIN
DECLARE nLast_val BIGINT;

SET nLast_val = (SELECT _sequence from seq_name = _seq_name);

IF (nLast_val IS NULL OR nLast_val = 0)THEN
    SET nLast_val = 1;
    INSERT INTO _sequence (seq_name, seq_val) values (_seq_name,nLast_val);
ELSE
    UPDATE _sequence  SET seq_val= @nLast_val = seq_val + 1 
    WHERE  seq_name= _seq_name
END IF;
RETURN nLast_val;
END 
DELIMITER ;
```

una vez realizado esto, solo debo llamar a la funcion getNextSeq("mitabla") y me devolvera el id de la tabla en curso y en el trigger por cada tabla debo tener mi id

```
|seq_name | seq_val |
| zona    | 3       |
| empresa | 32      |
| tienda  | 12      |
| tickets | 37      |
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola que tal ya logro hacer que de las 100 peticiones todas terminen correctamente ahora el problema reside al agregar el trigger AFTER INSERT que es donde se hacen muchas cosas (a otras tablas) ahora pienso que es por ese trigger que ocurre de nuevo el bloqueo de alguna tabla de igual manera comparto el código de ese trigger:

¿sera que tener todo este código en un trigger es demasiado?

```
DELIMITER
CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
    TRIGGER `tr_movimientos_A_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `tr_movimientos` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        ### Autor: Luis Roberto Muñiz Muñiz
        ### Fecha de creación: 2015-10-04
        ### versión 1.10
        ### Historial de modificaciones___
        ###         2015-10-08; Establecer variable de control; Agregar productos; Transacciones por fecha
        ###         2015-12-18; Se modifica el nombre de: sy_cubo__ventas_totales_modelos_UPDATE a: tr_movimientos_A_INSERT__sy_cubo. Se agregan Ajustes positivos y negativos
        ###         2016-02-02; Modifiqué costo_financiero por precio_financiero en el cálculo de las ventas_dinero. Agregé "dinero=dinero+(NEW.cantidad*NEW.precio_financiero)" al update de ventas diarias para mantener una estadística del dinero. Agregé el campo ",dinero" y el valor "NEW.precio_financiero" en el INSERT de las ventas diarias de producto.
        ###         2016-02-02; Alteración de tabla sy_cubo__segmentacion_modelos_cantidad, se agregaron los campos: ventas_dinero, ventas_dinero_costo, compras_dinero, existencia_cantidad, existencia_costo, existencia_precio
        ###         2016-02-02; Se agregan los campos anteriores a los Updates de los 4 diferentes tipos de movimientos que sy_cubo__segmentacion_modelos_cantidad contiene. Nota: En el tipo Compras no contamos con el precio
        ###             2016-02-08; Nuevo cubo de movimientos, sy_cubo__ventas_diarias_segmentacion. Se agrega el código que inserta y actualiza las transacciones de movimientos a el nuevo cubo
        ### Título: Actualziación de la cantidad de Ventas, Compras, etc del Modelo especificado al ingresar nuevas capas de inventario
        ### Nombre del objeto: sy_cubo__ventas_totales_modelos_UPDATE
        ### Disparador original: AFTER INSERT ON `tr_movimientos`
        #IF @sy_cubo__ventas_totales_modelos_UPDATE THEN
        # Actualiza la cantidad de venta/compra del modelo dentro del cubo
        DECLARE newFecha DATE;
        DECLARE idModelo LONG;
        DECLARE idProducto LONG;
        DECLARE Importe DOUBLE;
        DECLARE existe TINYINT(1);
        SET newFecha = (NEW.fecha_registro);
        ### Operaciones con modelos - Vertical Blive ###
        -- UPDATE sy_cubo__ventas_totales_modelos SET cantidad=cantidad+NEW.cantidad, dinero=dinero+(NEW.importe_bruto), dinero_netas = dinero_netas+(NEW.importe_final)
--      WHERE id_cat_zona=NEW.id_cat_zona AND id_cat_empresa=NEW.id_cat_empresa
--      AND tipo=NEW.tipo AND id_cat_modelo=NEW.id_cod_modelo;  
        # Actualiza la cantidad de venta/compra del modelo por dia
        ## comprueba que exista el producto en el cubo
        SET idModelo = (SELECT id_cat_modelo FROM sy_cubo__ventas_diarias_modelos
        WHERE id_cat_zona=NEW.id_cat_zona AND id_cat_empresa=NEW.id_cat_empresa
        AND tipo=NEW.tipo AND fecha=newFecha AND id_cat_modelo=NEW.id_cod_modelo LIMIT 1);
        IF (idModelo>0) THEN
            ## Si el proudcto SI existe...      
            ### Actualiza el registro encontrado en el cubo
            UPDATE sy_cubo__ventas_diarias_modelos SET cantidad=cantidad+new.cantidad, dinero=dinero+(NEW.importe_bruto),
            dinero_netas = dinero_netas+(NEW.importe_final), costo_acumulado = costo_acumulado+(NEW.costo_financiero * NEW.cantidad),
            precio_acumulado = precio_acumulado+(NEW.precio_financiero * NEW.cantidad) 
            WHERE id_cat_zona=NEW.id_cat_zona AND id_cat_empresa=NEW.id_cat_empresa
            AND tipo=new.tipo AND fecha=newFecha AND id_cat_modelo=idModelo;
        ELSE ## Si el producto NO existe...
            ### Inserta el modelo en el cubo al momento de su aparición como transacción en una nueva fecha.
            INSERT INTO sy_cubo__ventas_diarias_modelos (id_cat_zona,id_cat_empresa,fecha,tipo,id_cat_modelo,cod_modelo,cantidad,dinero,dinero_netas,costo_acumulado,precio_acumulado)
            VALUES (NEW.id_cat_zona,NEW.id_cat_empresa,newFecha,NEW.tipo,NEW.id_cod_modelo,NEW.cod_modelo,NEW.cantidad,NEW.importe_bruto,NEW.importe_final,
            NEW.costo_financiero * NEW.cantidad,NEW.precio_financiero * NEW.cantidad);          
        END IF;
    ###1-11-2016 Inserta la transaccion en el cubo de la socia
    
    SET idProducto = (SELECT id_cat_producto FROM sy_cubo_ventasdiarias_socias
            WHERE id_cat_zona=NEW.id_cat_zona AND   id_cat_empresa = NEW.id_cat_empresa AND id_cat_almacen=NEW.id_cod_almacen AND   fecha = newFecha AND cod_documento=NEW.cod_documento  AND
                tipo = NEW.tipo AND id_cat_cliente=NEW.id_cat_cliente AND   id_cat_producto = NEW.id_cod_producto LIMIT 1);
        
        IF (NEW.tipo='Ventas' OR NEW.tipo='DevolucionCliente') THEN 
        
            IF (idProducto>0) THEN
                UPDATE sy_cubo_ventasdiarias_socias SET   
                cantidad = cantidad+NEW.cantidad,  costo = costo+(NEW.costo_financiero * NEW.cantidad), precio=precio+(NEW.precio_financiero * NEW.cantidad ), precio_sin_iva=(NEW.importe_bruto)
                WHERE id_cat_zona=NEW.id_cat_zona AND   id_cat_empresa = NEW.id_cat_empresa AND id_cat_almacen=NEW.id_cod_almacen AND   fecha = newFecha AND cod_documento=NEW.cod_documento AND
                tipo = NEW.tipo AND id_cat_cliente=NEW.id_cat_cliente AND   id_cat_producto = NEW.id_cod_producto;
                
            ELSE ## Si el producto NO existe...
                INSERT INTO sy_cubo_ventasdiarias_socias(id_cat_zona, id_cat_empresa, id_cat_almacen,id_cat_cliente,cod_documento,id_cat_modelo, 
                id_cat_producto, fecha, tipo, cantidad, costo, precio,precio_sin_iva) 
                VALUES (NEW.id_cat_zona, NEW.id_cat_empresa,NEW.id_cod_almacen, NEW.id_cat_cliente,NEW.cod_documento,NEW.id_cod_modelo,
                NEW.id_cod_producto, newFecha, NEW.tipo, NEW.cantidad,
                (NEW.costo_financiero * NEW.cantidad ), (NEW.precio_financiero * NEW.cantidad ),NEW.importe_bruto);
            END IF; 
                            
        END IF; 
    
    ###1-11-2016 Termino la modificacion
    # Actualiza la INVENTARIO en el producto
    # Devolucion (devolución de proveedor) tiene signo positivo, +*- = -
    # DevoluciónClinte tiene signo negativo, -*- = + 
    
    ## 30-03-2017 Se realiza el anexo de la logica de trasaldo
    IF (NEW.tipo='Ventas' OR NEW.tipo='AjusteNegativo' OR NEW.tipo='Devoluciones') THEN 
        UPDATE cat_productos SET inventario=inventario-NEW.cantidad
        WHERE id_cat_zona=NEW.id_cat_zona AND id_cat_empresa=NEW.id_cat_empresa 
        AND eliminado=0 AND id_cat_producto=NEW.id_cod_producto;
    END IF;
    IF (NEW.tipo='Compras' OR NEW.tipo='AjustePositivo' OR NEW.tipo='DevolucionCliente' ) THEN 
        UPDATE cat_productos SET inventario=inventario+NEW.cantidad
        WHERE id_cat_zona=NEW.id_cat_zona AND id_cat_empresa=NEW.id_cat_empresa 
        AND eliminado=0 AND id_cat_producto=NEW.id_cod_producto;
    END IF;
    IF (NEW.tipo='Traslado' ) THEN 
        IF (NEW.naturaleza='Positivo' ) THEN 
            UPDATE cat_productos SET inventario=inventario+NEW.cantidad
            WHERE id_cat_zona=NEW.id_cat_zona AND id_cat_empresa=NEW.id_cat_empresa 
            AND eliminado=0 AND id_cat_producto=NEW.id_cod_producto;
        END IF; 
        IF (NEW.naturaleza='Negativo' ) THEN
            UPDATE cat_productos SET inventario=inventario-NEW.cantidad
            WHERE id_cat_zona=NEW.id_cat_zona AND id_cat_empresa=NEW.id_cat_empresa 
            AND eliminado=0 AND id_cat_producto=NEW.id_cod_producto;
         
        END IF; 
        END IF;
    # Actualiza la cantidad de venta del producto por dia
    ## comprueba que exista el producto en el cubo
    SET idProducto = (SELECT id_cat_producto FROM sy_cubo__ventas_diarias_productos
               WHERE id_cat_zona=NEW.id_cat_zona AND id_cat_empresa=NEW.id_cat_empresa AND naturaleza=NEW.naturaleza
               AND tipo=NEW.tipo AND fecha=newFecha AND id_cat_producto=NEW.id_cod_producto AND id_cat_almacen=NEW.id_cod_almacen LIMIT 1);
    ##Cambio 30-3-2017 Se desglosa la transaccionalidad  para que el  de ventas diarias de productos  reaccione  conforme al tipo de transacciones y se agrega las columnas de almacen 
    ##y desapaerece el cubo transaccional de almacenes   
    ## Si el proudcto SI existe...      
    IF (idProducto>0) THEN
    ## Actualiza las ventas diarias del producto en la fecha especificada
        
    IF (NEW.tipo<>'Traslado' ) THEN             
        UPDATE sy_cubo__ventas_diarias_productos SET cantidad=cantidad+NEW.cantidad, dinero=dinero+(NEW.importe_final), dinero_netas = dinero_netas+(NEW.importe_bruto),
        costo_acumulado = costo_acumulado+(NEW.costo_financiero * NEW.cantidad), precio_acumulado = precio_acumulado+(NEW.precio_financiero * NEW.cantidad),
        precio_sin_impuestos=precio_sin_impuestos+(NEW.importe_bruto),precio_con_impuestos=precio_con_impuestos+(NEW.importe_final)
        WHERE id_cat_zona=NEW.id_cat_zona AND id_cat_empresa=NEW.id_cat_empresa AND naturaleza=NEW.naturaleza
        AND tipo=new.tipo AND id_cat_almacen=NEW.id_cod_almacen AND fecha=newFecha AND id_cat_producto=idProducto;
     END IF;
     

    IF (NEW.tipo='Traslado' ) THEN 
        IF (NEW.naturaleza='Positivo' ) THEN 
            UPDATE sy_cubo__ventas_diarias_productos SET cantidad=cantidad+NEW.cantidad, dinero=dinero+(NEW.importe_final), dinero_netas = dinero_netas+(NEW.importe_bruto),
            costo_acumulado = costo_acumulado+(NEW.costo_financiero * NEW.cantidad), precio_acumulado = precio_acumulado+(NEW.precio_financiero * NEW.cantidad),
            precio_sin_impuestos=precio_sin_impuestos+(NEW.importe_bruto),precio_con_impuestos=precio_con_impuestos+(NEW.importe_final)
            WHERE id_cat_zona=NEW.id_cat_zona AND id_cat_empresa=NEW.id_cat_empresa AND naturaleza=NEW.naturaleza
            AND tipo=new.tipo AND id_cat_almacen=NEW.id_cod_almacen AND fecha=newFecha AND id_cat_producto=idProducto ;
        END IF; 
        IF (NEW.naturaleza='Negativo' ) THEN
            UPDATE sy_cubo__ventas_diarias_productos SET cantidad=cantidad-NEW.cantidad, dinero=dinero-(NEW.importe_final), dinero_netas = dinero_netas-(NEW.importe_bruto),
            costo_acumulado = costo_acumulado-(NEW.costo_financiero * NEW.cantidad), precio_acumulado = precio_acumulado-(NEW.precio_financiero * NEW.cantidad),
            precio_sin_impuestos=precio_sin_impuestos-(NEW.importe_bruto),precio_con_impuestos=precio_con_impuestos-(NEW.importe_final)
            WHERE id_cat_zona=NEW.id_cat_zona AND id_cat_empresa=NEW.id_cat_empresa AND naturaleza=NEW.naturaleza
            AND tipo=new.tipo AND id_cat_almacen=NEW.id_cod_almacen AND fecha=newFecha AND id_cat_producto=idProducto ;
         
        END IF; 
        END IF; 
        

    ELSE ## Si el producto NO existe...
        # Inserta el producto en el cubo al momento de su aparición como transacción en una nueva fecha.
        IF (NEW.tipo<>'Traslado' ) THEN 
            INSERT INTO sy_cubo__ventas_diarias_productos 
            (id_cat_zona,id_cat_empresa,id_cat_almacen,cod_almacen,fecha,tipo,id_cat_modelo,cod_modelo,id_cat_producto,cod_producto,cantidad,dinero,
            dinero_netas,costo_acumulado,precio_acumulado,naturaleza,precio_sin_impuestos,precio_con_impuestos) 
            VALUES (NEW.id_cat_zona,NEW.id_cat_empresa,NEW.id_cod_almacen,NEW.cod_almacen,newFecha,NEW.tipo,NEW.id_cod_modelo,NEW.cod_modelo,NEW.id_cod_producto,NEW.cod_producto,NEW.cantidad,
            NEW.importe_final,NEW.importe_bruto,NEW.costo_financiero * NEW.cantidad,NEW.precio_financiero * NEW.cantidad,NEW.naturaleza,NEW.importe_bruto,NEW.importe_final);
        END IF; 
        IF (NEW.tipo='Traslado' ) THEN 
            IF (NEW.naturaleza='Positivo' ) THEN 
                INSERT INTO sy_cubo__ventas_diarias_productos 
                (id_cat_zona,id_cat_empresa,id_cat_almacen,cod_almacen,fecha,
                tipo,id_cat_modelo,cod_modelo,id_cat_producto,cod_producto,cantidad,dinero,
                dinero_netas,costo_acumulado,precio_acumulado,naturaleza,precio_sin_impuestos,precio_con_impuestos) 
                VALUES (NEW.id_cat_zona,NEW.id_cat_empresa,NEW.id_cod_almacen,
                NEW.cod_almacen,newFecha,NEW.tipo,NEW.id_cod_modelo,NEW.cod_modelo,NEW.id_cod_producto,NEW.cod_producto,NEW.cantidad,
                NEW.importe_final,NEW.importe_bruto,NEW.costo_financiero * NEW.cantidad,NEW.precio_financiero * NEW.cantidad,NEW.naturaleza,NEW.importe_bruto,NEW.importe_final);
            END IF; 
            IF (NEW.naturaleza='Negativo' ) THEN
                INSERT INTO sy_cubo__ventas_diarias_productos 
                (id_cat_zona,id_cat_empresa,id_cat_almacen,cod_almacen,
                fecha,tipo,id_cat_modelo,cod_modelo,id_cat_producto,cod_producto,cantidad,dinero,
                dinero_netas,costo_acumulado,precio_acumulado,naturaleza,precio_sin_impuestos,precio_con_impuestos) 
                VALUES (NEW.id_cat_zona,NEW.id_cat_empresa,NEW.id_cod_almacen,
                NEW.cod_almacen,newFecha,NEW.tipo,NEW.id_cod_modelo,NEW.cod_modelo,NEW.id_cod_producto,NEW.cod_producto,-NEW.cantidad,
                -NEW.importe_final,-NEW.importe_bruto,NEW.costo_financiero * -NEW.cantidad,NEW.precio_financiero * -NEW.cantidad,NEW.naturaleza,NEW.importe_bruto,NEW.importe_final);
            END IF; 
        END IF; 
    END IF; 
            

    ###7-2-17 cambio para la transaccionalidad del cubo de almacenes
    SET idProducto=(SELECT id_cat_producto FROM `sy_cubo__inventario_por_almacen_producto`
     WHERE id_cat_zona=NEW.id_cat_zona AND id_cat_empresa=NEW.id_cat_empresa AND fecha=newFecha 
     AND id_cat_almacen=NEW.id_cod_almacen AND id_cat_producto=NEW.id_cod_producto AND  editable=1 LIMIT 1);
    ## Si el proudcto SI existe en el cubo de almacenes...      
    IF (idProducto>0) THEN
    IF (NEW.tipo='Ventas' OR NEW.tipo='AjusteNegativo' OR NEW.tipo='Devoluciones') THEN 
        UPDATE sy_cubo__inventario_por_almacen_producto SET cantidad=cantidad - NEW.cantidad,costo=costo-(NEW.costo_financiero*NEW.cantidad)
        WHERE id_cat_zona=NEW.id_cat_zona AND id_cat_empresa=NEW.id_cat_empresa AND fecha=newFecha AND id_cat_almacen=NEW.id_cod_almacen AND id_cat_producto=NEW.id_cod_producto  AND  editable=1;
            
    END IF;
    
    IF (NEW.tipo='Compras' OR NEW.tipo='AjustePositivo'  OR NEW.tipo='DevolucionCliente' ) THEN 
            UPDATE sy_cubo__inventario_por_almacen_producto SET cantidad=cantidad + NEW.cantidad, costo=costo+(NEW.costo_financiero*NEW.cantidad)
            WHERE id_cat_zona=NEW.id_cat_zona AND id_cat_empresa=NEW.id_cat_empresa AND fecha=newFecha AND id_cat_almacen=NEW.id_cod_almacen AND id_cat_producto=NEW.id_cod_producto  AND  editable=1;
            
    END IF;
    IF (NEW.tipo='Traslado' ) THEN 
        IF (NEW.naturaleza='Positivo' ) THEN 
            UPDATE sy_cubo__inventario_por_almacen_producto SET cantidad=cantidad + NEW.cantidad, costo=costo+(NEW.costo_financiero*NEW.cantidad)
            WHERE id_cat_zona=NEW.id_cat_zona AND id_cat_empresa=NEW.id_cat_empresa AND fecha=newFecha AND id_cat_almacen=NEW.id_cod_almacen AND id_cat_producto=NEW.id_cod_producto  AND  editable=1;
        END IF; 
        IF (NEW.naturaleza='Negativo') THEN 
                UPDATE sy_cubo__inventario_por_almacen_producto SET cantidad=cantidad - NEW.cantidad,costo=costo-(NEW.costo_financiero*NEW.cantidad)
                WHERE id_cat_zona=NEW.id_cat_zona AND id_cat_empresa=NEW.id_cat_empresa AND fecha=newFecha AND id_cat_almacen=NEW.id_cod_almacen AND id_cat_producto=NEW.id_cod_producto  AND  editable=1;  
        END IF; 
    END IF;
    ELSE
    ##############################  
    IF (NEW.tipo='Ventas' OR NEW.tipo='AjusteNegativo'  OR NEW.tipo='Devoluciones') THEN 
        INSERT INTO sy_cubo__inventario_por_almacen_producto (id_cat_zona, id_cat_empresa, fecha, id_cat_modelo, cod_modelo, id_cat_producto, cod_producto,
        id_cat_almacen, cod_almacen, cantidad, costo)
        VALUES (NEW.id_cat_zona,NEW.id_cat_empresa,newFecha,NEW.id_cod_modelo,NEW.cod_modelo,NEW.id_cod_producto,NEW.cod_producto,NEW.id_cod_almacen,NEW.cod_almacen, -1 * NEW.cantidad,
        (-1 * NEW.cantidad)*NEW.costo_financiero ); 
    END IF;
    IF (NEW.tipo='Compras' OR NEW.tipo='AjustePositivo' OR NEW.tipo='DevolucionCliente' ) THEN 
            INSERT INTO sy_cubo__inventario_por_almacen_producto (id_cat_zona, id_cat_empresa, fecha, id_cat_modelo, cod_modelo, id_cat_producto, cod_producto,
            id_cat_almacen, cod_almacen, cantidad, costo)
            VALUES (NEW.id_cat_zona,NEW.id_cat_empresa,newFecha,NEW.id_cod_modelo,NEW.cod_modelo,NEW.id_cod_producto,NEW.cod_producto,NEW.id_cod_almacen,NEW.cod_almacen, NEW.cantidad,
            NEW.cantidad*NEW.costo_financiero );
    END IF;
    IF (NEW.tipo='Traslado' ) THEN 
        IF (NEW.naturaleza='Positivo' ) THEN 
            INSERT INTO sy_cubo__inventario_por_almacen_producto (id_cat_zona, id_cat_empresa, fecha, id_cat_modelo, cod_modelo, id_cat_producto, cod_producto,
                 id_cat_almacen, cod_almacen, cantidad, costo)
                 VALUES (NEW.id_cat_zona,NEW.id_cat_empresa,newFecha,NEW.id_cod_modelo,NEW.cod_modelo,NEW.id_cod_producto,NEW.cod_producto,NEW.id_cod_almacen,NEW.cod_almacen, NEW.cantidad,
             NEW.cantidad*NEW.costo_financiero );
        END IF; 
        IF (NEW.naturaleza='Negativo' ) THEN 
            INSERT INTO sy_cubo__inventario_por_almacen_producto (id_cat_zona, id_cat_empresa, fecha, id_cat_modelo, cod_modelo, id_cat_producto, cod_producto,
            id_cat_almacen, cod_almacen, cantidad, costo)
            VALUES (NEW.id_cat_zona,NEW.id_cat_empresa,newFecha,NEW.id_cod_modelo,NEW.cod_modelo,NEW.id_cod_producto,NEW.cod_producto,NEW.id_cod_almacen,NEW.cod_almacen, -1 * NEW.cantidad,
            (-1 * NEW.cantidad)*NEW.costo_financiero ); 
        END IF; 
    END IF;
END IF;###7-2-17 termina el cambio de transacionalidad      
END;
DELIMITER
```